# Javascript not working after filename change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, initialization

I created a simple registration (sign-up) form for my website.

The form includes a few validity checks (such as : making sure that the email is in the correct format; making sure that the username does not already exist in the database; etc, etc)

All these required JS, which I provided with the proper JS functions, and included a JS script with my files :

```
 **<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
```

Everything was working perfectly..........until I changed the name of my registration file from "**index.html**"  to "**signup.php**"

Now, it's all screwed up.  The form still works. But, the JS functions and validity checks are dead!  Nothing works.

There are no similar issues here on StackOverflow;  however, I was able to find one issue on google.  The poster suggested using a "Javascript Initialization" to solve the issue, but he did not provide an example of exactly how he did this.

Here is my JS code :

```
 <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {  

//the min chars for username  
var min_chars = 4;  

//result texts  
var characters_error = 'You must enter a minimum of 4 characters!';  
var checking_html = 'Checking Username Availability....';  

//when button is clicked  
$('#login').keyup(function(){    
    //run the character number check  
    if($('#login').val().length < min_chars){  
        //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '  
        $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error);  
    }else{  
        //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check  
        $('#username_availability_result').html(checking_html);  
        check_availability();  
    }  
 });  

 $('#email').keyup(function(){    
    //run the character number check  
    if($('#email').val().length > 0 ) {  
        //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '  
        $('#email_availability_result').html(checking_email);
         }
    else{  
        //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check  
        $('#email_availability_result').html(checking_email);  
        check_email();  
    }  
  });

 });  

//function to check username AND email availability  

function check_availability(){  

//get the username  
var login = $('#login').val(); 
var button_check=true;

//use ajax to run the check  
$.post("check.php", { login: login },  
    function(result){  
        //if the result is 1  
        if(result == 1){  
            //show that the username is available  
            button_check=false; 
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            $('#username_availability_result').html(login + ' is    
     available.');  
        }else{  
            //show that the username is NOT available 
            button_check=true; 
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            $('#username_availability_result').html('Sorry, but [' + login +  
     '] is not available. Please choose another username.');
             }  
    });  
   }
```

This script checks for "username availability" and also that the username has "a minimum of 4 characters" and also "email availability", etc, etc

(I did not enter the full code, as I assume it is not necessary).  These are just examples of part of my code.

And here is the form  (the input entry for username)

Choose a username :

**UPDATE**

I solved the issue of why the JS functions were not working :  I had to specify the FULL PATH to the JS source-file, beginning with **https://**......etc.

However, something still remains unclear :  the form displays the message "Checking Username Availability".........or "Checking Email Validity".  But, if the username is available/unavailable, or email is valid/invalid.........it does not display these messages!

The "Checking Username Availability" message remains stuck on display :((

Comment: Have you checked if the javascript file is still loaded on your page? Have you tried creating a simple Jquery like `show` or `hide` of DOM elements?

Comment: Never heard on something like that. Consider checking for js errors in your browser's console (developer tools, `F12`)

Comment: It's probably something in the 90% of the page you haven't shown, as you've changed from html to php, perhaps something in the unseen part of the page is causing problems with the php "preprocessor", (for want of a better term)

Comment: I found the issue :  full path is needed. :)    I updated my post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer found.

A simple, stupid mistake on my part (haha)

After changing the file name to "sign-up.php",  I forgot to remove the PHP extension. So, naturally, my server did not know where to look for it

Comment: It is good that you are willing to share your solution with others. However, typo error corrections as answers are not going to help much. In such cases, you could either remove your question (or) self flag/vote to close it.

Comment: Well, in the future I'll make sure to NOT bother !!